# Installing and trying jesque-web

Tags: java, redis, jetty, jedis, jesque

I am running [redis](http://redis.io/) on my laptop for trying out and learning with default config file located at `/etc/redis/6379.conf`. you can see at http://paste.ubuntu.com/10678722/

I want to try [jesque-web](https://github.com/gresrun/jesque-web) on my laptop so to install and trying I followed steps given on its homepage.

1. Download source
   `git clone https://github.com/gresrun/jesque-web.git`
2. edited config file `jesque-web-master/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/redis.properties` with values
   redis.host=127.0.0.1
   redis.port=6379
   redis.timeout=0
   redis.password=
   redis.namespace=resque
   redis.database=16
3. Finally Starting Jetty for trying
   `mvn -Pjetty-run clean test`

After 3rd step jetty server starts and I am able to open http://localhost:8080 but page is showing errors  `redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool`

all the errors can be seen at http://paste.ubuntu.com/10678929/

Its looking like that there is some configuration problem. I tried to find out on the internet to on installing and setting up Jesque-Web and that error but could not find anything relevant for me. someone please tell me where and what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

it works fine on setting
`redis.database=o`
or
`redis.database=1`

in `jesque-web-master/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/redis.properties`
the value 0 or 1 is name of database in redis. In redis database name is integer value.